# Why does the random number never equal 4.0?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate random numbers with up to 2 decimal places until one equals 4.0, but it's never ending.

```
count = 0


while(random != 4.00):
    print(round(random.uniform(0.00,4.00),2))
    count = count + 1
    if random == 4.00:
        print('DONE')
        print(count)
```

Comment: `random` is the `random` module, not any of the random numbers you're generating. A module will not equal `4.00`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I’m voting to close this, I can’t see it ever being relevant in the future.

Comment: @AMC this **is** an MRE, but I agree that this likely won't be helpful to others

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Is it? At the very least we’re missing the import for random, although there could always be more.

Comment: @AMC import statements are very often left out in questions (for the worse), so when a variable uses the name of a common module/package, it is usually safe to imply the variable refers to that module/package.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Agreed!

Answer (score 2):

You're not testing the random number you're generating. You need to assign it to a variable and test that.

```
while True:
    r = round(random.uniform(0.00,4.00),2)
    print(r)
    count = count + 1
    if r == 4.00:
        print('DONE')
        print(count)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `while random != 4.0` is checking if the **module** named *random* is not equal to `4.0`, not the number generated on each loop.

To fix this you need to use a **variable**:

```
import random
count = 0

while True:
    n = round(random.uniform(0.00,4.00), 2)
    count += 1
    if n == 4.00:
        print('DONE')
        print(count)
        break
```